# Get Exposed Filter Value

Tags: views

How does one get the actual value for an exposed filter?

I can get the 'id' for a filter value using the following code and pulling the data out of the array, but this just returns integer values of 1,2,3,etc.:

```
$view = views_get_current_view();
$view->exposed_input['filter_name'];
```

using `$view->get_exposed_input()` results in the exact same issue.

How do I get the actual text string that is applied for the filter?

Specifically I'm trying to do this with a Global PHP field.

Comment: Can you confirm Drupal and Views versions?  Think it actually matters here, as it will be slightly different in Drupal 7 vs Drupal 8.  And, a *really* good answer for this question would show the method for both versions. :)

Comment: Drupal 7, Views 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is by using a Taxonomy to define your filter. By default, the 'IDs' returned in the array will be TIDs, which you can link back to Term name.

[This post](https://ffwagency.com/blog/views-taxonomy-links-as-exposed-filter-ajax-enabled-for-drupal-7) provides some easy instructions on how to use a Taxonomy as your filter (you possibly need to add it as a relationship in your view)

Get your IDs (values) the same way previously:

```
$view = views_get_current_view();
$view->exposed_input['filter_name'];
```

Then simply step through the array to pick up and match the IDs to the term name:

```
$view = views_get_current_view();
foreach ($view->exposed_input['filter_name'] as $tid) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
  $name = $term->name;
  print $name;
}
```

Boom!

Answer (score 0):

To get both filter name and its value, you can do something like that :

**Make a variable out of each filter**

```
function MODULE_preprocess_exposed_filter_data(&$vars) {

  $view = $vars['view'];

  // In case no view - get the current view
  if ($view == NULL) {
    $view = views_get_current_view();
  }

  if (isset($view->exposed_input)) {
    foreach ($view->exposed_input as $filter => $value) {
      $vars[$filter] = $value;
      if (is_array($value)) { 
        $vars['exposed_filters'][$filter] = check_plain(implode(", ", $value));
      } else {
        $vars['exposed_filters'][$filter] = check_plain($value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Declare your template**

```
function MODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'exposed_filter_data' => array(
      'template' => 'exposed_filter_data',
      'variables' => array(
        'view' => NULL,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Call to template output**

```
function get_exposed_filter_output() {
  return theme('exposed_filter_data');
}
```

**In `exposed_filter_data.tpl.php` file**

```
<?php if (isset($exposed_filters)): ?>
  <div class="exposed_filter_data">
    <div class="title"><?php print t('Filtered by:'); ?></div>
    <div class="content">
      <?php foreach ($exposed_filters as $filter => $value): 
      //Do stuff with your filters and values here ?>
        <?php if ($value): ?>

        //taxonomy terms for instance
        if ($filter == 'field_taxonomy_tid') : 
          if($value != '' && $value != 'All' ){ 

            $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
            $vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_load($term->vid);
            $vocab_name = $vocab->name; ?>

            <div class="filter">
              <div class="name">$vocab_name :</div>
              <div class="value">
                <?php $types = explode(',', $value);
                $t = taxonomy_term_load_multiple ($types);
                $exp_types = '';
                foreach ($t as $k=>$v) {

                  $exp_types .= $v-> name . ', ';                

                }
                $exp_types = substr($exp_types, 0, -2);
                print $exp_types;
                ?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php }
          endif; 
        <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Finally print your exposed filter data : instead of using global PHP in your view, you'd better try something like that :

```
function MODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if ( $view->name == 'MYVIEWNAME' ){
    //display exposed filters in a custom text area
    if (isset($view->header['area_text_custom'])){
      $exp = get_exposed_filter_output();
      $view->header['area_text_custom']->options['content'] = $exp;
    }
  }
}
```

This is 80% inspired by this little handy module : [Exposed Filter Data](https://www.drupal.org/project/exposed_filter_data)

Comment: Thanks @Kojo for the comprehensive answer. I haven't tried yours but I stumbled upon a solution playing with Taxonomies to define the filter.